# Log file produce from my reboot script in powershell is missing some servers

Tags: multithreading, powershell, logging, monitoring, restart

When I run my script it reboots my servers listed in my csv file and also monitors the progress of when my machines are online, when they go offline, and when they come back up. When this happens they are appended to a log file so i can see the progress since the scripts are run in script blocks. For some strange reason when it tries to reboot multiple servers the log files it produces is always different. Sometimes everything shows as it should be, other times all the servers that are online will be listed but when listed what servers have gone offline during reboot it may only show 10 of the 15 servers. But when i check all my servers manually they all come back online during reboot but log file doesn't document it.

The servers I am rebooting range from 2008r2 servers to 2012. The older servers take longer to reboot then the newer ones. What I am thinking is happening is that since this is all happening in Parallel the log file is missing logging the progress of those servers due to some of them going offline as the same time of some confusing the script. If that is the case how would i resolve this issue?

```
#Credentials used to invoke commands on servers
$Creds = Get-Credential

Function Write-and-Log ($Message)
{
    Write-Host (Get-Date -Format ("[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss] ")) "$message" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    (Get-Date -Format ("[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss] ")) + "$message" | out-file $logfilename -Append
}

#variables
$ScriptRoot = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$StartTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss_"
$csvfile = $ScriptRoot + "\" + "servers.csv"
$logdir = $ScriptRoot + "\serverLogs\"
$logfilename = $logdir + $StartTime + "Reboot.log"

#Import servers from vms2deploy.csv file
$Servers = Import-Csv -Path $csvfile

#Script block for rebooting servers
$deploy_Reboot_scriptBlock = { 
(gwmi -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName "$env:computername").Win32Shutdown(6)
}
#End of Scriptblock

#script block for monitoring servers
$monitor = {
Param ( $Computer, $logfile, $logfile1 , $logfile2,                      
 [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$False,Mandatory=$False)]            
 [int]$timeout=5            
)            

$MAX_PINGTIME = $timeout * 60            
$max_iterations = $MAX_PINGTIME/5            

function ping-host {            
param($pc)            
$status = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address='$pc'"            
if( $status.statuscode -eq 0) {            
   return 1            
} else {            
 return 0            
}            
}            

if(ping-host -pc $computer) {            
 (Get-Date -Format ("[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss] ")) + "$Computer is online; Waiting for it to go offline" | out-file $logfile -Append          
 $status = "online"            
 for ($i=0; $i -le $max_iterations; $i++) {            
  if (!(ping-host -pc $computer )) {            
   break            
  }            
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 5         
  if($i -eq $max_iterations) {            
   (Get-Date -Format ("[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss] ")) + "$Computer never went down in last $timeout minutes" | out-file $logfile -Append
   (Get-Date -Format ("[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss] ")) + "Check that reboot is initiated properly" | out-file $logfile -Append            
   show-notification -type "error" -text "$computer is still ONLINE; Check that reboot is initiated properly" -title "Computer is not rebooting"            
   exit            
  }            
    }            

    (Get-Date -Format ("[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss] ")) + "$Computer is offline now; monitoring for online status" | out-file $logfile1 -Append              

} else {            
    (Get-Date -Format ("[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss] ")) + "$Computer is offline; Monitoring for online status" | out-file $logfile -Append             
    $status = "offline"            
}            

for ($i=0; $i -le $max_iterations; $i++) {            
 if ((ping-host -pc $computer )) {            
  break            
 }            

 Start-Sleep -Seconds 5            
 if($i -eq $max_iterations) {            
  (Get-Date -Format ("[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss] ")) + "Your computer never came back online in last $MAX_PINGTIME seconds" | out-file $logfile -Append             
  (Get-Date -Format ("[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss] ")) + "Check that nothing is preventing starup" | out-file $logfile -Append             
  show-notification -type "error" -text "$Computer is NOT coming online; Something is preventing its startup" -title "Computer failed to start"            
  exit            
 }            
}            

(Get-Date -Format ("[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss] ")) + "$Computer is Online Now; Task done; exiting" | out-file $logfile2 -Append             
show-notification -type "info" -text "$Computer is online" -title "$Computer successfully restarted"
}
#scriptblock end
Foreach ($server in $Servers){       
        $Session = $Server.name
        Write-and-Log ":Info: Restart command issued to $Session"        
        New-PSSession -ComputerName $Session -Credential $Creds           
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Session -ScriptBlock $deploy_Reboot_scriptblock -AsJob -Credential $Creds
        $Computer = $Session
        $logfile = $logdir + $StartTime +  "monitor.log"
        $logfile1 = $logdir + $StartTime +  "monitor1.log"
        $logfile2 = $logdir + $StartTime +  "monitor2.log"
        Write-And-Log "Monitoring reboot process for $computer"
        $jobs_tab += @{ $server = start-job -name $server -scriptblock $monitor -argumentlist $Computer, $logfile, $logfile1, $logfile2 }



}

#track the job progress 
do{
    #do not repeat too often
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    Write-And-Log  "Checking to see status of reboot jobs"
    $running_jobs = 0

    foreach ($server in $Servers) {
        if ($($jobs_tab.Get_Item($server)).state -eq "running") {
            $running_jobs++
        }
    }    
    #until we are out of active jobs
} until ($running_jobs -eq 0)
```

Log file results 
Monitor log

```
[2017-11-30 12:18:17] server1 is online; Waiting for it to go offline
[2017-11-30 12:18:17] server2 is online; Waiting for it to go offline
[2017-11-30 12:18:18] server3 is online; Waiting for it to go offline
[2017-11-30 12:18:19] server4 is online; Waiting for it to go offline
[2017-11-30 12:18:19] server5 is online; Waiting for it to go offline
[2017-11-30 12:18:20] server6 is online; Waiting for it to go offline
[2017-11-30 12:18:20] server7 is online; Waiting for it to go offline
[2017-11-30 12:18:21] server8 is online; Waiting for it to go offline
[2017-11-30 12:18:21] server9 is online; Waiting for it to go offline
[2017-11-30 12:18:22] server10 is online; Waiting for it to go offline
[2017-11-30 12:18:25] server11 is online; Waiting for it to go offline
[2017-11-30 12:18:27] server12 is online; Waiting for it to go offline
[2017-11-30 12:18:32] server13 is online; Waiting for it to go offline
[2017-11-30 12:18:33] server14 is online; Waiting for it to go offline
```

monitor1 log

```
[2017-11-30 12:18:32] server1 is offline now; monitoring for online status
[2017-11-30 12:18:35] server2 is offline now; monitoring for online status
[2017-11-30 12:18:36] server3 is offline now; monitoring for online status
[2017-11-30 12:18:36] server4 is offline now; monitoring for online status
[2017-11-30 12:18:37] server5 is offline now; monitoring for online status
[2017-11-30 12:18:38] server6 is offline now; monitoring for online status
[2017-11-30 12:18:39] server7 is offline now; monitoring for online status
[2017-11-30 12:18:39] server8 is offline now; monitoring for online status
[2017-11-30 12:18:41] server9 is offline now; monitoring for online status
[2017-11-30 12:18:44] server10 is offline now; monitoring for online status
[2017-11-30 12:18:45] server11 is offline now; monitoring for online status
[2017-11-30 12:18:46] server12 is offline now; monitoring for online status
```

monitor2 log

```
[2017-11-30 12:18:41] server1 is Online Now; Task done; exiting
[2017-11-30 12:18:44] server2 is Online Now; Task done; exiting
[2017-11-30 12:18:45] server3 is Online Now; Task done; exiting
[2017-11-30 12:18:45] server3 is Online Now; Task done; exiting
[2017-11-30 12:18:46] server4 is Online Now; Task done; exiting
[2017-11-30 12:18:47] server5 is Online Now; Task done; exiting
[2017-11-30 12:18:48] server6 is Online Now; Task done; exiting
[2017-11-30 12:18:48] server7 is Online Now; Task done; exiting
[2017-11-30 12:18:50] server8 is Online Now; Task done; exiting
[2017-11-30 12:18:53] server9 is Online Now; Task done; exiting
[2017-11-30 12:18:54] server10 is Online Now; Task done; exiting
[2017-11-30 12:18:55] server11 is Online Now; Task done; exiting
```

As you can see after the first monitor log they don't match up. Each log should have the same number of servers. They may not be in the same order but they should all be there.

Comment: Chances are that you are running into sharing violations from multiple jobs trying to write to the same log at the same time.

Comment: @Shawn Esterman Made those changes but got the same result. The only log that had the same time stamp was reboot log. That log just shows the script being run for the servers and tells me how long the job has to finish. It made no changes to the logs in my script block

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I had similar thoughts as well So I tried splitting the log file. Before The three monitor log files were just one, after splitting them I was hoping there wouldn't be any more issues but they remained.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the date multiple times. Every time you run `Get-Date` that time will be different, even if slightly. Store the time in a variable and use that to update all of your log files with the same timestamp.

```
# Store this in your variable once per loop
$DateTime = Get-Date

# When you create your string for your log file, use this instead
$DateTime.ToString('[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]')
```